# Salesforce Test Class - System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: salesforce

Salesforce Test Class - Facing - System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Error while trying to Run Test Class

APEX class

```
public class NewAccountCreation {
public Account account{get;set;}
public void save(){
Account acc = new Account();
// User enter values in vf page and we are capturing and creating account
acc.name = account.Name;
//acc.address = account.adress;
Insert acc;
}
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
public class TestNewAccountCreation {
    @isTest static void TestNewAccountCreationMethod(){
        NewAccountCreation testAccount = new NewAccountCreation ();
        Account acc = new Account(Name='TestAcct');
        Insert acc;
        system.debug(''+acc);
        testAccount.save();
        System.assert([Select Id From Account].size()==1);
    }
}
```

Error:
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

StackTrace:
Class.NewAccountCreation.save: line 6, column 1
Class.TestNewAccountCreation.TestNewAccountCreationMethod: line 9, column 1

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set `testAccount.account`, so it's `null`. You *do* need to populate this variable, and you *do not* need to create and insert an `Account` in your test code. In fact, doing so will cause your assertion to fail.